# Kendo Tabstrip MVC Adding Dynamic Number of Tabs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, kendo-ui-mvc

I am building a tab based web application.

I can load a new tab from javascript using this code after an AJAX call:

```
 tabStrip.append(
 {
      encoded: false,
      id: id,
      text: name + html,
      content: divData                        
 });
```

But, I now have a need to load some tabs at startup, and if I knew how many to load (and it didn't ever change) I can do it this way in Razor:

```
.Items(items =>
{
    items.Add().Text("Home").Content(@Html.Action("Load","Home").ToHtmlString()).Selected(true);
    items.Add().Text(Model[0].Name).HtmlAttributes(new { id = Model[0].Id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) }).Content(@Html.Action("Index", Model[0].Controller).ToHtmlString());
    items.Add().Text(Model[1].Name).HtmlAttributes(new { id = Model[1].Id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) }).Content(@Html.Action("Index", Model[1].Controller).ToHtmlString());
}
```

But in the BindTo syntax, I can get only so far:

```
.BindTo(Model, (item, tab) =>
{
    item.Text = tab.Name;  //Needs to not be encoded!
    item.ContentUrl = tab.Url;
    item.Id = Id does not exist!
       or 
    item.HtmlAttributes = cannot be set!
})
```

Unfortunately there are really no good examples out on the KendoUI website beyond the most basic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use "manual bind" like this:

```
.Items(items =>
{
    foreach (var tab in Model.MyTabs) {
        // any logic you need here, for example 
       items
          .Add()
          .Text(tab.Name)
          .HtmlAttributes(new { id = tab.Id.ToString() })
          .Content(@Html.Partial("MyTabView", tab.Model).ToHtmlString());
    }
}
```

So basically if you have dynamic collection of tabs, you can just iterate through this collection manually and configure each tab individually - you need not to use `BindTo` here.